# How do I auto-increment windows store package versions on Team Builds from TFS?

Tags: windows-8, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

We are developing a windows 8 Metro application right now, and have it correctly setup to create new ARM and x86 app packages on each check-in to our staging branch.

However, the problem is that the package creation process keeps giving it a version of 1.0.0.0.  This then makes packages unable to be installed on tablets and computers that already have the application installed, because it sees that it's installed with the same version but the actual application is different.

I tried setting the `AssemblyVersion` to `1.0.*`, but since the assembly version and package version are completely different (which sucks), how can I get TFS team build to automatically set the package version on build so new builds can be installed on Windows 8 systems?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Win 8 apps, but setting the assembly version should be the same as for normal .Net I guess. We set the versions every time in our build, while the Revision is the same as the actual changeset used for build. That way it will be increased automatically if some one checked in anything in the Project Collection.
First step is to get the changeset number and set the other versions:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <incMajorVersion>6</incMajorVersion>
 <incMinorVersion>1</incMinorVersion>
 <incBuildNumber>3</incBuildNumber>
 <incRevision>$(SourceGetVersion.Replace("C",""))</incRevision>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Next step is to find the assembly files and change the versions to the specified ones. To do this a MSBuild task is used from Extensionpack (http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.5.0/Index.html). Now we have to import the task file, find the assembly files and change them. This needs to be done before anything else happens, so we override the AfterGet target:

```
<Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>

<Target Name="AfterGet" DependsOnTargets="$(AfterGetDependsOn)">
 <ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyInfoFiles Include="$(BuildDirectory)\**\AssemblyInfo.cs"/>
 </ItemGroup>

 <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.AssemblyInfo
  AssemblyInfoFiles="@(AssemblyInfoFiles)"
  AssemblyMajorVersion="$(incMajorVersion)"
  AssemblyMinorVersion="$(incMinorVersion)"
  AssemblyBuildNumber="$(incBuildNumber)"
  AssemblyRevision="$(incRevision)"
  AssemblyFileMajorVersion="$(incMajorVersion)"
  AssemblyFileMinorVersion="$(incMinorVersion)"
  AssemblyFileBuildNumber="$(incBuildNumber)"
  AssemblyFileRevision="$(incRevision)" />
</Target>
```

Now the output files should have the version number you defined.

Comment: You need to define this in a MSBuild project file (e.g.  TFSBuild.proj). I don't use these XAML style build processes, but if you use them, it should be possible to insert a execute command after the get, that calls a MSBuild with the AssemblyUpdate.

Comment: Unfortunately, package versions are completely separate from assembly versions :(.  WinRT apps have both, which is retarded, and for windows store and install purposes all it cares about is package version not assembly version.  However, your post does help me with assembly versioning our non-Winrt apps so thanks!

Comment: But where does it get the package version from? Is there an additional setting in AssemblyInfo or a special file for that?